Where does Calibre E-book viewer store annotations?
When I open an EPUB file, a JSON file is created in ~/.config/calibre/viewer/annots/ with information such as last position, highlights/annotations etc. However, if I delete the JSON files from viewer/annots and I re-open the e-book, the highlights/annotations are still there.
Within the viewer, the option to "Keep a copy of annotations/bookmarks in the e-book file, for easy sharing" is unchecked (under Preferences > Miscellaneous), but in order to confirm, I made a copy of the e-book, added some highlights in the copy and checked the md5sum for both files, which were identical. I also put a keyword in the annotation and used Calibre's E-book editor to search for the keyword in the contents of the EPUB, but couldn't find it.
So, it looks like annotations are not stored in the e-books themselves and they're not coming from the (deleted) JSON files in viewer/annots, so why do they persist and where are they stored?
System info

Kubuntu 22.04
Calibre 5.37


When the Calibre E-book viewer is used to add annotations to a text, the data is stored in the text's accompanying .opf file in the Calibre Library.
For example, in an annotation added to The Nurserymatograph - A Lawyer.epub below, sharing a folder with metadata.opf, the data is stored in the HTML section
<meta name="calibre:annotation" content="... "/>


Of course, one can make another app the default to open a text (as I have done, because the Calibre E-book viewer is abysmally slow to start), in which case annotations would be stored elsewhere.
